# How to justify a delay simply

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

How can I justify a delay in office due inclement bad weather..actual case is my flight got delayed by 3 hrs and I reached late to office, because of such delay production has hampered. Now clients are asking for preventive action. Although it's a natural weather issue no one can do anything, but then to I have to justify it. All suggestions are very well come.

Comment: This is probably better at Workplace.SE, or else this question would be about writing advice or how to be tactful in the workplace.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better asked at Workplace.SE.

Answer (score 1):

I'd refer them to the legal parlance of an **Act of God**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Act_of_God

It sounds grandiose, but that's literally the term used in rental agreements and the like for weather events for which no one (tenant or landlord) is responsible - that's basically what you experienced. They should understand why you don't have to justify a delayed flight, you shouldn't have to understand how to explain it away.